# How to update nested state or values in Typescript and Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having Typescript errors if I try to update nested values of an object. This is my code.

```
type InterviewType = {
    time: string;
    person_name: string;
}
type FormState = {
    description: string | undefined;
    interviews: InteviewType[] | undefined;
};

const [formState, setFormState] = useState<FormState>({
    description: '',
    interviews: [],
});

useEffect(() => {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      description: interviewData?.data.description,
      interviews: interviewData?.data.interviews,
    });
}, [interviewData]);
```

`interviewData` might be like this

```
{
    data: {
        description: 'Some Description',
        interviews: [
            {
                time: '10:00 AM',
                person_name: 'xyz'
            },
            {
                time: '10:10 AM',
                person_name: 'xyz2'
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

When I try to update the time with a new value dynamically by the below code, it is giving me an error

```
setFormState({
    ...formState,
    interviews: {
      ...formState.interviews,
      [index]: {
        ...formState.interviews[index],
        'time': val,
      },
    },
});
```

> Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
> Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.  TS2322

Now, I can ignore this error by providing ignore ts comment and the code is working fine. But my reviewer didn't accept it and wanted me to remove ignore comments. Any solution or different way to this issue?

```
setFormState({
    ...formState,
    interviews: {
        // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
      ...formState.interviews,
      [index]: {
        // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
        ...formState.interviews[index],
        'time': val,
      },
    },
});
```

And somehow if I am able to avoid this error by implementing different logic then a new one will come saying `Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.  TS2533`. BTW `interviewData` is coming from the API. Hence it is obvious that `fromState.interviews` will be `undefined or null` initially. So, how can I avoid this error too?

Comment: Where is this `number` type coming from if you didn't specify (neither implicitly nor explicitly) it anywhere?

Comment: `interviews` should be an array, right? Your update code try to update it with an object

Comment: @k-wasilewski I am wondering myself but unable to find it that where it's coming from?

Comment: @Doppio `interviews` is an array of objects. I have tried to update by `interviews: [` in updating formdata but then it is giving more errors in inner code.

Comment: `interviews: {
      ...formState.interviews,
      [index]: {
        ...formState.interviews[index],
        'time': val,
      },
    },
` this looks like object, not array

Comment: @Doppio then how to update like an array? Could you please provide me the code?

Answer (score 1):

*Answering how to update array at index.*

Assuming you want to update interview time at `index`

What the code does is, it loop through the interviews array, if the index match the index we want to update, we return a new updated object { ...interview, time: newTime }, else we keep the same object.

```
const updateInterview = (atIndex, newTime) => {
  setFormState({
    ...formState,
    interviews: formState.interviews.map((interview, i) => {
      if (atIndex === i) return { ...interview, time: newTime };
      return interview;
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Tried your code and now error changed to `Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.  TS2533` if I put this line `// @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.` on line no 4  in your code, it is working. Which I don't want.

Comment: I have solved `Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.  TS2533` error by adding `?` after the array. `interviews: formState.interviews?.map`. So it would be like if `formState.interviews` has some value then only execute the loop.